# How do I randomize the questions pulled from my dictionary-plist

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

Hey Guys any ideas for randomising the questions that I pull from my -plist file?

```
-(NSUInteger)nextQuestionID:(NSUInteger)question_number{
return (question_number>=[self.questions count]-1) ? 0 : (question_number+1);
return 0;

}

-(NSDictionary*) getQuestion:(NSUInteger)question_number{
if (question_number>=[self.questions count]) question_number = 0;
return [self.questions objectAtIndex:question_number];
return NULL;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a random integer, I would suggest using `arc4random` function, here is some code to do this:

```
int randomInt = arc4random() % questionNumber;
return [self.questions objectAtIndex: randomInt];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `arc4random_uniform(upper_bound)` function. The parameter is the upper bound of your random number.

An example:

```
int index = arc4random_uniform([self.question count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`question_number = arc4random() % self.questions.count;`

Comment: Thank you Ali for your help, I have tried to put this in but it doesn't appear to be working, I am putting it in like this which i guess is wrong   

-(NSUInteger)nextQuestionID:(NSUInteger)question_number{
 return (question_number>=[self.questions count]-1) ? 0 : (question_number+1);
 return 0;
}

-(NSDictionary*) getQuestion:(NSUInteger)question_number{
 if (question_number>= arc4random() % [self.questions count]) question_number = arc4random();
 return [self.questions objectAtIndex:question_number];
 return NULL;
}

Comment: Errr do you even understand what you are writing?! Basically you just wrote "generate a random number, then **if `question_number` is greater than or equal to this random number then** regenerate another random number". What do you expect this code would do?

Answer (score 0):

set question number as random number

replace the function

```
-(NSDictionary*) getQuestion:(NSUInteger)question_number{
   if (question_number>=[self.questions count]) question_number = 0;
   question_number = arc4random()%[self.questions count];// changes made here
   return [self.questions objectAtIndex:question_number];
   return NULL;


}
```

Comment: From `man arc4random` - `[arc4random] ... is recommended over constructions like "arc4random() % upper_bound" as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.`

Answer (score 0):

the random integers:

```
srand(time(nil));
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    NSLog(@"random number between 72 and 96 : %d", rand() % (96 - 72) + 72);
}
```

**UPDATE**

and for your specific case:

```
- (NSUInteger)nextQuestionID {
    srand(time(nil));
    return rand() % [self.questions count];
}

- (NSDictionary*)getQuestion {
    return [self.questions objectAtIndex:[self nextQuestionID]];
}
```

**UPDATE#2**

test the following loop two, three or more times and compare the outputs:

```
srand(time(nil));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSLog(@"random number : %d", rand() % 89 + 10);
}
```

you should get 10 random numbers between 10 and 99, I've tested it on a real device, not on the simulator but it should work on the simulator as well.

**if you get the same result always, let me know.**

Comment: Hello holex, we have entered the code as you suggested but it doesn't appear to be pulling the random questions out, here is what we have entered. 
    -(NSUInteger)nextQuestionID:(NSUInteger)question_number{
        srand(time(nil));
        return rand() % [self.questions count];
    }

    -(NSDictionary*) getQuestion:(NSUInteger)question_number{
     if (question_number>=[self.questions count]) question_number = 0;
 return [self.questions objectAtIndex:question_number];
 return NULL;
}

Comment: Thank you for your help Holex, I am still struggling to get this to work, I have replaced my code with that above but still no luck, am I missing anything that I need to have in order to get this to work correctly? Sorry to ask so many questions I am new to this all. Thank you.

Comment: how do you mean _you struggle_? it gives back random questionIDs from database i.e. my last test gave this questionIDs of 400: `294, 185, 182, 321, 373, 252, 162, 23, 224, 352, 188, 238, 325, 396, 239, 270, 235, 355, 47, 191, 136, 107, 275, 170, 338, 79, 8, 266, 294, 61, 1, 10, 184, 166, 102, 17, 68, 83, 200, 25, 282, 338, 132, 4, 59, 189, 212, 283, 203, 144, 303, 95, 255, 273, 327, 274, 266, 121, 278, 346, 130, 71, 369, 353, 49, 355, 157, 339, 301, 139, 47, 40, 316, 239, 11, 212, 100, 220, 199, 80, 152, 208, 86, 133, 249`... it looks random for me. what does make problem still?

Comment: My code just gives me the same questions in the same order as always, I have no idea why or what I can do about it. I am assuming I am missing a section of code or have got something in here that is preventing it from working. Thank you again for your help in advance

Comment: please, do the test what I mentioned under the **update#2** section in my updated answer.